AWS RDS vs. AWS Timestream for real-time balance calculations
In a large scale project, a S3 bucket will be receiving thousands of CSV files / minute. The CSV files contain numeric usage data related to users. At any given time, this data will be used to calculate user balance [credits/money].
Which AWS service would fit better: AWS RDS or AWS Timestream? Especially, when it comes to reliability, scalability and ability to stream in real-time S3 data into the databases (for live-streaming I am considering using SNS, SQS and Lambda).
